# Redux-saga task cancellation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm having serious trouble getting this task to cancel. It's inside a small loop, and it runs fine if I use `takeLatest` inside the accumulator at the bottom of the function. Nothing happens/the `flowControl` function appears not to run if I use `take`.

The cancel action fires, but the task keeps right on running - is this a problem with using `while`? Is this another problem I'm not seeing?

If the problem is in exporting this flow using the `*appRoot` at the bottom of the page, how does one properly include a flow-control into a React/Redux store?

```
function* install() {
  const items = list.length - 1; // total number of things to call
  let count = 1;

  while (count < items) {
    const response = yield call(() => Promise.resolve(list[count]));
    if (response && !response.error) {
      yield put({type: LOAD_ITEM_SUCCESS, item: response.data});
      console.log('success, created new item', response.data);
    }
    yield delay(5000);
  }
}

export function* flowControl() {
  while ( true ) {
    // starts the task in the background
    const task = yield fork(install);
    // wait for the user stop action
    yield take(CANCEL_ACTION, cancelInstall, task);
  }
}

function* cancelInstall(task){
  yield cancel(task);
}


export default function* appRoot() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(LOAD_ITEMS, flowControl)
  ]);
}
```

Update For Others Post-Rubber-Duck Here:

- Issue 1: The while loop inside `flowControl` is not falsifiable, so it runs forever
- Issue 2: `take` does not work as expected, but replacing it with `takeLatest` fires the cancellation function properly.

Though [present in the demos](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/TaskCancellation.html), the `while` loop hasn't got a falsifiable state, so it just ... runs. A bunch! I'm not sure why, but removing the `FlowControl` while and replacing the cancellation `take` with `takeLatest` makes this flow work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[take](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takepattern) receives a single argument.

Retry with this change:

```
export function* flowControl() {
  while ( true ) {
    // starts the task in the background
    const task = yield fork(install);
    // wait for the user stop action
    yield take(CANCEL_ACTION); // <-
    yield call(cancelInstall, task); // <-
  }
}
```